# Revision limit not enforced: How do I selectively remove entry revisions?

Tags: entries, revisions

I have just been clicking around my four year old EE instance (which got recently upgraded from version 2 to 3), and found something quite odd:

Several channel entries are having many more revisions than the limit is supposed to cap at '10' (my current settings). In one case it's more than a hundred revisions stored and I am not sure how this came about. Perhaps I've had this set to a higher number in the past, but I'm wondering why it's not limiting it to the number of revisions like it's supposed to.

I'm also using the Structure add-on and have checked if there are any settings that could possibly override the CP settings. Seems to be unrelated to Structure.

I know that I can delete all revisions associated to a whole channel, but I'd rather not do that.

My questions related to this:

**How can I make it behave like it's supposed to? i.e. Limit to 10 revisions.**

**How can I keep the latest 10 revision entries but discard the older ones?**

I can live with this, but it seems non-standard behaviour and eventually could lead to concerns about performance. And also it's quite strange to have to scroll down all the way just to find the more recent revisions I would like to see. (The fixed sorting lists older ones first).

*edit: I have just updated to 3.5.3. And changed the limit to 11, submitted and cleared caches. If I can't get it fixed in the next two weeks i'll probably just remove all revisions and then start anew. Still, help with this would be appreciated. I've also posted it to the official forums, as it's likely a bug.*